# Android Get UTC time from ntp server

Tags: android, networking, time, utc, ntp

i'm trying to get the current UTC time of a server, but it give me  te zone time (UTC+6), Is there any way to have the UTC time without using the device time?

My code:

```
NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("time1.google.com");
TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
long returnTime = timeInfo.getMessage().getOriginateTimeStamp().getTime();
long returnTime2 = timeInfo.getReturnTime();
Date current = new Date(returnTime);
Date current1 = new Date(returnTime2);
Log.i("actualtime", current.toString()); //it give me UTC+6
Log.i("actualtime",current1.toString()); //it give me UTC+6
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date.toString()` always returns timezone-specific output. Your `returnTime` variable is probably actually the proper epoch time: if you want to print out UTC, use `SimpleDateFormat` to do it. Something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println("UTC time: " + fmt.format(current));
```

Comment: That still uses device time. Change your device time and test the code again